# Crash when accessing matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to create a 2D array to represent a weighted graph. To make the matrix I am making an array of arrays, as shown in the constructor below. This matrix will store the weight of the edges connecting two nodes. For example graph[1][2] would store the weight of the edge between points 1 and 2.

```
Weighted_graph::Weighted_graph( int n ):vertices(n){
double **graph= new double *[vertices];
nodeDegree=new int [n];
edges=0;
for (int c=0;c<vertices;c++)
{       
    graph[c] = new double[vertices];
    nodeDegree[c]=0;    
    for (int d=0;d<vertices;d++)
    {   
        graph[c][d]=INF;
    }   
}
```

}

with graph defined as `double **graph;`

This  seems to work until I try to access the variable graph from other functions at which point the program crashes. (INF is properly defined further down in the code).

Comment: There's insufficient info to answer this question. You need to show the code that's actually crashing as well. On first glance, though, double** graph is defined in this function and never returned. How are other functions going to know what value you assigned to it?

Comment: What `patros` and `Fritschy` are saying is, other variables aren't accessing this particular variable named `graph`, whose scope is limited to the constructor shown.  They may be accessing some other variable with the same name, but it's still a different variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are referencing the graph member of the object you are constructing. However, graph is declared as a local variable there.

Comment: Yep, it was a scope issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's all about scope, because you are in a function you can re-use a variable name, but this one is only accessible in the instructor. Remove the double** from in front of graph in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Comment: It is for a school project, I had to do it this way.